# Prove function is Lipschitz'

Tags: calculus

$$f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}\text{ has continuous partial derivatives. }$$

$$\exists k>0 \text{ so that, }\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(X)\right| \leqslant k \text{ for all } X\in \mathbb{R}^m \text{ and } j=1,\dots ,m$$

Prove that $f$ is Lipschitz function, for every $X,Y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ following inequality holds $|f(X)-f(Y)| \leqslant L||X-Y||$.

How should I approach this problem? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider the function $g(t)=f(X+t(Y-X))$ for $0<t<1$ then calculate $g'(t)$.

After calculating $g'(t)$ calculate $f(Y)-f(X)$ ...